# Jira rest api insert custom fields in create issue

Tags: json, jira, jira-rest-api

I have following custom field. How do i pass it in JSON to create issue in jira using rest api

```
"customfield_10300":{  
   "required":false,
   "schema":{  
      "type":"option",
      "custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
      "customId":10300
   },
   "name":"Severity",
   "hasDefaultValue":false,
   "operations":[  
      "set"
   ],
   "allowedValues":[  
      {  
         "self":"http://sjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10303",
         "value":"Blocker",
         "id":"10303"
      },
      {  
         "self":"http://sjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10304",
         "value":"Critical",
         "id":"10304"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: no this is not a duplicate

Comment: You want to add it to the `create issue view` ?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: i want to isert new issue in jira through json which has the above custom field. i tried following but it is giving me error 400 Bad request.

Comment: this is the custom field :- "customfield_10200":{"required":false,"schema":{"type":"array","items":"option","custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:multiselect","customId":10200},"name":"Test phase","hasDefaultValue":false,"operations":["add","set","remove"],"allowedValues":[
{"self":"http://sjira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10202","value":"Functional Smoke test","id":"10202"}

Comment: i tried this but its giving me 400 bad request. "customfield_10200":{"id":"10202"}

Answer (score 1):

As the field is from type "select" you should use the JSON format to populate a select field:

Here an example:

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       { 
          "key": "PKEY"
       },
       "summary": "Your summary",
       "description": "your description",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Task"
       },       
       "customfield_10013": { "value": "Blocker" }       
   }
}
```

Some more details can be found here: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue